# How to get urls from twitter api that appear as "http://t.co/..."?

Tags: api, url, twitter, hyperlink, entities

I realized sometimes the links in the tweets are shortened and this happens "http://t.co/…".
The problem is that when this happens the url never appears in the entities and I need those.
Does anyone knows how to get these urls?

example:

```
{
"created_at": "Fri Sep 06 15:00:59 +0000 2013",
"id": 375997059792650240,
"id_str": "375997059792650240",
"text": "RT @BreakingNews: 2-month-old baby boy in Minneapolis hit by stray bullet Thursday night; in critical condition - @StarTribune http://t.co/…",
"source": "TweetCaster for Android",
"truncated": false,
"in_reply_to_status_id": null,
"in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
"in_reply_to_user_id": null,
"in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
"in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
"user": {},
"geo": null,
"coordinates": null,
"place": null,
"contributors": null,
"retweeted_status": {},
"retweet_count": 55,
"favorite_count": 0,
"entities": {
"hashtags": [],
"symbols": [],
"urls": [],
"user_mentions": []
},
"favorited": false,
"retweeted": false,
"lang": "en"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to retrieve these is to submit a HEAD request, i.e.:

```
curl -s -I https://t.co/........ | grep location
```

But using your HTTP library of choice of course.

Comment: The problem is that the urls aren't complete. In the "text" field they appear as for example "http://t.co/…", and this is an invalid (incomplete) url.